# Vaadin Disable Browser Spell Checking in TextField?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

Vaadin 7.6.2

How to disable Spell Checking in a TextField component?  Googled and searched Stack, the few answers given don't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add [Viritin add-on](https://vaadin.com/addon/viritin) (use latest version) to your project, then configure your field with following code:

```
TextField field = new MTextField().withSpellCheckOff();
```

Alternatively you can use the low level API to configure the html element (works for example TextArea);

```
new HtmlElementPropertySetter(yourTextInputComponent).setProperty(
                "spellcheck", false);
```

Comment: The doesn't seem to work.  I'm using like "new HtmlElementPropertySetter(firstName).setProperty("spellcheck", "false");"  Spell check still occurring in Safari and Chrome on that field.  The "firstName" field is defined as a TextField component.

Comment: Dough, there was a typing issue in (untyped!) JS stuff :-) Browser changed "false" string into *true*. Changed Viritin in 1.46 to let user pass in other basic types as well and in now works properly in my Safari and Chrome.

Comment: Is withAutocompleteOff() correct camel case?  Should it be withAutoCompleteOff() ?  (given the camel case of the other methods.

Comment: I've created a start for a MComboBox (see: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/3c6815cf8cba48a8b04b). I've implemented a selectAll() that works, but could be implemented better by someone who knows the underlining Vaadin framework better than I. Feel free to update or mod this.